# Default constructor for a class with a reference data member?

Tags: c++, reference, default-constructor, class-members

I have a class `MyClass` in which I need to create a `std::array` of `std::vector` in the default constructor. However, this class has a data member which is a reference (of type `Something`) which also needs to be initialized in the constructor and I cannot do this in a default constructor.

How should I solve this?

```
class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass(); //Cannot instantiate s??
    MyClass(Something& s);
    Something& s;
}

MyClass array[10];   // MyClass needs a default constructor but a default 
                     // constructor won't be able to initialize s
```

Comment: Can you give us a simple code example of this to illustrate the problem?

Comment: But by the description alone, I would say that it's a classical case where `s` should be a `Something*` rather than a `Something&`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A class with a reference member needs to set the reference in its constructors. In most cases this means, that the class cannot have a default constructor. The best way to solve the problem is use a pointer instead of a reference:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass() : s_(0) {}
    MyClass(Something* s) : s_(s) {}
    Something* s_;
}
```

Comment: Technically speaking, it _can_ have a default constructor (e.g. if it stores a reference to a global in `s_`).  The problem is that you have to make the reference "point" to an `Something` instance.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented above, by the description alone, I would say that it's a classical case where `s` should be a `Something*` rather than a `Something&`...

OTOH, this work perfectly, so you don't ***need*** a default constructor *if you just initialize each element of your array*:

```
struct Something { };

struct MyClass {
  MyClass(Something& ss) : s{ss} {}
  Something& s;
};

int main() {
  Something a, b, c, d;
  Something v[10] = { a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d, a, b };
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thats because you have used a list initializer whereas I do not have the elements to add to the array to begin with :)

Comment: Well, you can always do `MyClass() : s{sx} {}; static Something sx;`

Answer (score 1):

Your can also do this:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass() : s_(0) {}
    MyClass(Something& s) : s_(&s) {}
    Something* s_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<Something>>` instead of `Something&`, this way you simulate `Something*` behavior but using modern C++ concepts.
note that you should check if member variable defined this way has value by calling `has_value` function and get the actual reference value by `s_.value().get()`
you also could use `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const Something>>` if you need a const reference to Something